# Change home directory for gnuplot

Tags: command-line, programming

Is there a way to change the gnuplot home directory permanently to a home/user/gnuplot directory without typing

> cd home/user/gnuplot

after every gnuplot start?

Comment: Can you explain better what you want. You lost me there for a minute. Where is the gnuplot initially.

Comment: without doing any settings gnuplot reads data files from the home/user directory but I want a subdirectory for all my data files I want to plot with gnuplot. For plotting a file out of this directory I must change the path to /home/user/gnuplot after every gnuplot start manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around I found this link: http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-6900018

Which has the following info:

18 Start-up

> When gnuplot is run, it looks for an initialization file to load. This
>   file is called .gnuplot on Unix and AmigaOS systems, and GNUPLOT.INI
>   on other systems. If this file is not found in the current directory,
>   the program will look for it in the HOME directory (under AmigaOS,
>   Atari(single)TOS, MS-DOS, Windows and OS/2, the environment variable
>   GNUPLOT should contain the name of this directory; on Windows NT, it
>   will use USERPROFILE if GNUPLOT isn’t defined). Note: if NOCWDRC is
>   defined during the installation, gnuplot will not read from the
>   current directory.
>
> If the initialization file is found, gnuplot executes the commands in
>   it. These may be any legal gnuplot commands, but typically they are
>   limited to setting the terminal and defining frequently-used functions
>   or variables.

which means that it reads into your home directory if the file is not found BUT it also checks for the GNUPLOT variable which contains the name of this directory. So just jumping into a conclusion I have not tested since I do not have gnuplot but yo might like to try it you can do something like this in the terminal:

`GNUPLOT = /home/user/gnuplot` that way you set the GNUPLOT variable to that particular value. Before doing this I recommend to see what value GNUPLOT has before. type this: `echo $GNUPLOT`

the other is creating the file the program is looking for in the directory where the program is (gnuplot.ini) and if this file has some variable that tells it where to read, yo might like to try that other method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have now created a .gnuplot file and inserted the gnuplot command to open path: `cd "\home/user/gnuplot` I did not know before, that gnuplot automatically executes this .gnuplot file

Comment: If it works correctly please accept the answer. If not let us know to continue with the help.